# Export curve / path from blender to Three.js

Tags: three.js, blender, curve, bezier, spline

I have a very simple scene and I want to export a bezier curve / nurbs curve to JSON. Nothing I do seems to export anything. I can export meshes etc.

I'm sure I have done this in the past but I have no idea how to do it anymore.

Thanx a lot!

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://superuser.com because it's not a programming question.

Comment: My apologies! I posted it there as well :-)
http://superuser.com/questions/1141961/export-curve-path-from-blender-to-three-js

Comment: @Jorisvanr Any Progress on this issue? I have the exact same problem